# does Homeopathy medicine work

Tags: medical-science

Almost all scientists say homeopathy a fake. Can I trust these.
Is there any proof that this system works.

Homeopathy doctors say it works. what is true

Comment: The consideration of it working, is that you put such a low dose of the item that it bypasses your normal censors of what constitutes "health" (because if what YOU called health was enough, you wouldn't need medicine).